# function not executing with localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to use localStorage to compare values on two html pages and increase by 1 the number of a given field if the values correspond. However unsuccessful even after adjusting the code a number of times and trying different versions. Any help is appreciated.

Below please find the code for html1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html id='test'>
       <head>
         <link href='test.css' rel='stylesheet'>
       </head>
       <body>
         <table>
             <tr>
                <td rowspan="2"><img src='../icons/profile-picture.png'></td>
                <td class='John'>
                    <span id='current-name'>John Hamish Smith</span>
                </td>
             </tr>
             <tr> 
                <td colspan="2">
                    <textarea id='billing' placeholder="Type here" cols='28' rows='8'></textarea>
                    <p id='new-billing'>0</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script>
            const currentName = document.getElementById('current-name');
            const otherPageName = localStorage.getItem('name');
            const test = document.getElementById('new-billing');
            let page = document.getElementById('test');
            const testing = () => {
                if(currentName.value === otherPageName.value) {
                    test ++
                } 
            } 
            page.addEventListener('load', testing);
            
         </script>
      </body>
   </html>
```

and here for html2

```
<!DOCType html>
   <html>
      <p id='name'>John Hamish Smith</p>
      <script>
        const name = document.getElementById('name');
        localStorage.setItem('name', name);
      </script>
   </html>
```

---

Update: following @Hannah's response - thank you I have updated as follows:

html 1:

```
<script>
            const currentName = document.getElementById('current-name').textContent;
            const otherPageName = localStorage.getItem('name');
            // const test = Number(document.getElementById('new-billing').textContent);
            const newBillingField = document.getElementById('new-billing');
            const currBillingValue = Number(newBillingField.textContent);
            const newBillingValue = currBillingValue + 1;
            
            let page = document.getElementById('test');
            const testing = () => {
                if(currentName === otherPageName) {
                    newBillingField.textContent = newBillingValue;
                } 
            } 
            page.addEventListener('load', testing);
            



            
        </script>
```

and html2:

```
<p id='name'>John Hamish Smith</p>
    <script>
        const name = document.getElementById('name').textContent;
        localStorage.setItem('name', name);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to store a object, not an string. The correct way:

```js
let name = document.getElementById('name').innerText;
localStorage.setItem('name', name);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not fetching the value from inside your `new-billing` div, you are only storing the node itself. Try updating that line to this:

```
const test = Number(document.getElementById('new-billing').textContent);
```

However if you want to update the value *displayed* in the field, you can't just do `test++`, you need to do it like this:

```
const newBillingField = document.getElementById('new-billing');
const currBillingValue = Number(newBillingField.textContent);
const newBillingValue = currBillingValue + 1;
newBillingField.textContent = newBillingValue;
```

For comparing the names: in your html2 file, try `const name = document.getElementById('name').textContent` instead - currently you are storing the HTML node in localStorage instead of the value. Then in html1:

```
const currentName = document.getElementById('current-name').textContent;
const otherPageName = localStorage.getItem('name');
if(currentName === otherPageName) ...
```

Comment: Thank you @Hannah! this is great help and I understand my mistake. I have now updated my code above as I still don't have a '1' instead of '0'.... not sure if you know why?

Comment: Are you sure that your `testing()` method is firing? You could attach it to the `window` instead - e.g. `window.addEventListener('load', testing)`

Comment: Still nothing @Hannah, it is odd, I also tried to use an external js file and use onload on the html tag in the first html instead and still nothing. The function testing is not running - I included an alert inside to test it too. But the js file is well linked, I tested the alert outside the function too....